# Configuration of XBee network with multiple end devices

Tags: xbee, sleep

How do I configure an xbee network with multiple end devices (each connected to sensor and microcontroller) and one coordinator (connected to the PC)?

Do I use AT mode or API mode? What is main difference between them?

In this type of network, when two end devices transmit data will there be interference between them? If so, how to avoid?

Some one told me the XBee sleep mode is used for this type of network but how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The sensor XBees won't interfere with each other. The mode depends on if the PC needs to send data to the sensors.

If it doesn't (all data is one-way), you can set the sensor XBees' destination address to the PC one's address.

If it does, and it is ok for all the sensors to get the same message, you can configure the PC XBee to broadcast.

If the PC needs to send messages to one sensor at a time, use API mode (or configure the destination address on the fly, entering programming mode might be too slow).